how to transfer data to mikrotik router using netmiko?
I would be appreciated if you could help me to transfer some data to my mikrotik router via netmiko in python.
I already wrote this code but its not working.
Mikrotik = {
        'device_type': 'mikrotik_routeros',
        'host':'host',
       'username': '****',
        'password': '***',
        'port': '22',
        }

from netmiko import ConnectHandler

ssh_conn = ConnectHandler(**Mikrotik)

source_file = "C:/Users/text.txt"
dest_file = "test1.txt"
direction = "put"
file_system = "flash:"

transfer_dict = file_transfer(
    ssh_conn,
    source_file=source_file,
    dest_file=dest_file,
    file_system=file_system,
    direction=direction,
    overwrite_file=True,
)

what am I doing wrong? or is there another way to do this
